# Save data to local drive and USB storage device simultaneously

Tags: backup, data-backup, live-backup

Here's my system design:
Laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
Linksys/Cisco WRT610N Router
Western Digital 1 TB external hard drive attached to WRT610N via USB storage

Here's my question:
Is it possible to save data to the laptop's local drive and WD USB external hard drive simultaneously?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Note sure about exactly the same time but Western Digital provides Western Digital Smartware and that can be configured to copy data from specified locations on the local drive to an attached WD drive. This happens automatically and once configured, requires no interaction from you.  What is backed up can be easily modified at any time. Works seamlessley for me withn a WD drive connected to the USB port of a D-Link router.

Comment: Thank you, Dave!  I know WD Smartware will work w/WD My Book Live external drives but my WD external is an Elements drive; will it also work on Elements?

Comment: Sorry I can't say for certain buy perhaps download the software from the WD site and try it out

Comment: I'll download Smartware, install it, and see if it recognizes the WD Elements drive.  Thanks, Dave!  You've been very helpful.